# "Never join already wrapped lines" for Javascript source formatter

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Eclpise (Helios) Java formatter has "Never join already wrapped lines" configuration option. Is there any similar option for Javascript files?

Comment: I want this too.  Did you find an answer ever?

Comment: Have you considered using the Aptana plugin for eclipse? it adds a code formatter that I use, after some configuration its behaving reasonably.
http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse go to help > install new software and add this repo:

```
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
```

after installing the aptana plugin you should have some new javascript formatting options available.
including never join already warped lines.

you will have to change your .js file associations to use the aptana editor (and it may be a good idea to change .html files too)

you can find a rough guide on how to change file associations in eclipse here:

```
http://www.andyscott.id.au/blog/Setting-up-file-associations-in-Eclipse
```

I'm sure you've sorted this issue out by now but im leaving this answer here for the benefit of anyone else that finds this question.

Comment: I doesn't seem to have that kind of formatter option. I've checked Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Formatter -> JavaScript -> edit. Is that option present there or am I looking at wrong place?

Comment: I see, then you could consider Spket, it has a lot more formatting options, as-well as in depth options for code formatting see here: http://george-gray.co.uk/images/spket.JPG

get the eclipse plugin version here: 

http://www.spket.com/download.html